# Formatar Calendário de input em HTML5 com javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, validação

Estou fazendo um formulário com validação em HTML5 e me deparei com uma situação um pouco ruim, quando coloco por exemplo `type="date"` quando passo o mouse em cima aparece as "setinhas" pra manipular data ou ascender ao calendário. O problema é que a formatação dele é horrível e eu gostaria de saber se não tem como eu usar ou `CSS` ou `JAVASCRIPT` para resolver este problema.

```
 <input type="date" name="DtNascimento" required="required" 
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Por favor, digite sua Data de Nascimento.')" 
onChange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">
```

Comment: Existem algumas bibliotecas que já te fornecem uma formatação melhor como o [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [jquery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) e [este](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/).

Comment: Acho que vou usar o DatePicker timer mesmo então, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Para problemas de formatação de campos eu uso bibliotecas javascript.

Na minha opinião a melhor para datas é a DatePicker
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Lucas          Eu ja tinha visto esse datetimepicker mas postei aqui pra saber se realmente havia uma solução em cima desse do HTML5. Bom, pelo jeito terei de usar javascript mesmo.